# How to use PIVOT in SQL Server to convert a set of values into a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

Suppose I have the following table result from sql query :

[image]

I want the result look like the following :

[image]

I want to pivot the result using currency column, so the values of currency will become columns, but I do not want to have a column for every currency, I want to aggregate for example the sum for 2 specific currencies one column.

Is that possible using PIVOT in sql? If so, how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Images of data really don't help us help you. Please do take the time to provide sample data in a consumable format; either tabular format `text` or DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using conditional aggregation. This is a cross-database solution, and there is no performance penalty compared to vendor-specific `pivot` syntax (it might even perform better):

```
select
    line_id,
    sum(case when currency in ('USD', 'GBP') then amount else 0 end) currency_group1,
    sum(case when currency in ('AUD', 'CAD') then amount else 0 end) currency_group2
from mytable
group by line_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GMB's solution.

If you really must, and want a quick hack as a pivot plus a link to the documentation
[MS PIVOT DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)
:

```
SELECT LineID,  
  USD+GBP,AUD+CAD
FROM  
    (SELECT lineID,cur,amnt from #cash ) as s
PIVOT  
(  
    sum (amnt) 
FOR   
cur  
    IN ( [USD],[GBP],[AUD],[CAD])  
) AS piv
```

What are problems with this solution?

1. Any Null data will kill any sum. You can't sum a null and it will remove both figures you are adding together. As such you must wrap the figures in isnull(Column,replacement_data).  `isnull(USD,0)+isnull(GBP,0)`  [ISNULL DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. If you were to only use pivots and do it properly, you would have to join 4 pivots with a separate where clause per currency EG  from #cash WHERE currency = 'USD'. This is why GMB's case statement solution is much simpler to write and read.